# Django generic view - clarification on extra_context property - github vs installed source

Tags: django, django-generic-views

So i was digging in Django's source codes and came across these two:
[`views.generic.list.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py) and [`views.generic.base.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py)

so this is line 26 in `base.py` in `ContextMixin`'s `get_context_data` method

```
if self.extra_context is not None:
    kwargs.update(self.extra_context)
return kwargs
```

`MultipleObjectMixin` (line 9 in `list.py`) inherits `ContextMixin` and calls the parent class's method in the overwritten `get_context_data` method (line 136 in `list.py`)

So the `extra_context` variable should work and add extra context to the dictionary passed to template engine in classes that use the `MultipleObjectMixin`.
But the questions i looked up stated that `extra_context` isn't supported anymore, and i ran a code that didn't work and i had to overwrite `get_context_data` to get what i wanted, does anyone have any explanations about this?

**P.S.**
I checked the installed sources on my system, and it was different than the github code, so my question now is why is the repository behind from latest released versions?

Comment: You are linking to the master branch (which will become Django 2.0). You should look at the tag for the specific version you are using, e.g. 1.11.

Comment: I've been using generic views a LOT (subclassing them, adding mixins, etc) and have not seen this.  It must be something new.  But I can't think of too often that I only add things to the context that are known at compile time.. so it makes more sense to just override get_context_data anyway.

Comment: ContextMixin's `extra_context` was added [just over a month ago](https://github.com/django/django/commit/604341c85fe42c809d17ea2418566a48f60f78db) to the current master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i saw a question about `extra_context` which was about Djnago 1.5 or something close to that, so i assumed the feature existed and was removed and that gave me the impression that the master branch is behind from the latest release
But as it seems, and @knbk pointed out, it's a newly added (or maybe *revived*) feature.

So, i guess this explains everything. I'd be happy to accept any more complete answer if anyone has one :) or I'll just go with my own answer to close this question.